# IE 10 too impatient for VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-10

My new development machine is running Windows 8 64-bit with IE 10.

When I start to debug a web application using VS 2012 with IIS Express as the web server, IE 10 soon reports

```
This page can't be displayed
 o Make sure the web address http://localhost:9999 is correct
```

Refreshing IE 10 brings up the page I am trying to debug.  This was never an issue on my older (and slower) Win 7 / VS 2012 / IE 9 setup debugging the same code.  It is consistently reproducible.

Is there a setting I can tweak to instruct IE 10 to wait another second or two for VS 2012 to serve `http://localhost:9999`?

Comment: Filed as issue on Connect https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770973/ie-10-too-impatient-for-vs2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `ReceiveTimeout` setting in the registry.  For me, it was set to 10000ms (10 seconds).

Change that value to the desired number of milliseconds.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ReceiveTimeout

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181050?wa=wsignin1.0